# Evaluate the limit as $x$ approaches $3$ : $\displaystyle\frac{x^3 -6x+2}{x^2+2x-3}$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the limit x approaches 3 : $\displaystyle\frac{x^3 -6x+2}{x^2+2x-3}$

I am currently doing a limit problem, will be doing many in the coming months. I was wondering how do I factor a cube such as $x^3 -6x+2$? Is there a special rule?

The ones I am familiar with are  $$a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)(a^2 – ab + b^2)$$ 
$$a^3 – b^3 = (a – b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$$

but that does not work here. I also can not factor anything out.

Comment: Google *Rational Root Theorem*. If you're supposed to factor is, then this will help you $99%$ of the time. Perhaps it would be better if you changed the nature of your question to include the limit instead of just asking about the arithmetic (though there's nothing wrong with your question as it is).

Comment: *factor it, 99%. You should also try to factor the denominator, not just the numerator. In this particular case that will help.

Comment: I get (x-1) and (x+3). That does not help me cancel out anything in the numerator.

Comment: I guess I should just substitute the 3. Let me try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x) = x^{3} -6x +2$ and $g(x) = x^{2} +2x-3$

You have $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ = $\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)}$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and obviously $g(x)\ne {0}$ when $x\rightarrow a$

Here $a=3$

so for $x \rightarrow 3$ :

$f(x) \rightarrow 11$

and $g(x) \rightarrow 12$

The final limit is : $\frac{11}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

If it can be factored, a cubic polynomial will have two factors whose degrees add up to 3.  So if we disregard constant factors, it would be the product of a first degree and a second degree factor.

In this particular example, $x^3 -6x +2$, it cannot be done with polynomials having integer coefficients.  We say the polynomial is *irreducible* over the integers because it cannot be factored, and the easy way to show this is applying [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) with the prime $p=2$.

Comment: Since it's cubic, the rational root theorem decides irreducibility. (maybe simpler than Eisenstein..)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to factor numerator or denominator because at $x\to3$ numerator and denominator are defined and denominator isn't $0$, so just write:
$$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{x^3-6x+2}{x^2+2x-3}=\frac{3^3-6\cdot3+2}{3^2+2\cdot3-3}=\frac{11}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your need to factor the fraction should only arise when it is tending to an indeterminate form $0\over 0$. Here you can simply put 3 and evaluate the limit which comes out to $11\over12$.